# Find number of ways to seat $n$ boys and $n$ girls in a row so that every boy has at least one girl sitting beside him.

Tags: combinatorics

My attempt: I am getting $2^n(n!)^2$ .

First I paired $n$ boys and $n$ girls in $n!$ ways then these pairs can be arranged in $n!$ ways and in each of these pairs boy and girl can arrange themselves in $2!$ ways.

Comment: Do it with $2,3$ (girls boy) and then generalize

Comment: You can never get GGBBGB in your count, but it is valid and has the same number of girls and boys like you require

Comment: I also get $2^n(n!)^2$, by taking $n = 1, 2, 3$.

Comment: @Tim: Well how are you getting it? Is your method counting GGBBBG as a solution (incorrectly) and also missing Ross's solution?

Comment: @user21820 Why would i count GGBBBG? no 3 boys could occur together, and 2 boys cant be at terminal end. keeping that in mind, i found it to be $2^n(n!)^2$ And yes GGBBGB will be a valid count, but what i think Ross means is that we will be unable to count GGBBGB..

Comment: @Tim: That is my point. Unless you explain your method, I do believe that you have counted wrongly, for example excluding Ross's solution. Stella's solution is wrong for exactly the same reason, and counts GGBBBG as a solution.

Comment: I dont know how you presume that i am counting GGBBBG just by looking at the answer. What I was doing is take n = 1, 2 , 3. Then write out all possible permutations of $B$ and $G$ considering all Bs and Gs are same. 

For n = 1 : $BG$ and $GB$

For n = 2 $BGBG$, $GBGB$, $GBBG$, and $BGGB$

For n = 3 can't enlist here, but i got 8.

So in general, we get $2^n$
Once i got the arrangements, i acknowledge that all B and G are different and we can reorder them in $n!$ way each, so we get total: $2^n\times n!\times n!$

Comment: @Tim: Just because you got $2^n$ ways for $n \in {1,2,3}$, you then conclude that it is $2^n$ for any positive integer $n$?? That's my whole point..

Comment: @Tim: The question was about arbitrary $n$, and in your first comment you nowhere stated that you only dealt with $n \in \{1,2,3\}$, and that is why I assumed you had a method in mind, like Stella's, which is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35328/discussion-between-tim-and-user21820).

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: I'm not sure what you meant in your first comment, since you implied in another comment that you don't believe there's a closed form.

Comment: No i was just telling the op to see whether she/he can conclude the closed form in all cases as it isnt the case i thought numbers would clear up the mistake

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: Ahh right. Do you see any faster way than in my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Begin with seating $n$ indistinguishable girls leaving ample space between and around  them, like so:
$$\ \underline{\ \  }\ G\ \underline{\ \ }\ G\ \underline{\ \ }\ G\ \underline{\ \ }\ \ldots\ \underline{\ \ }\ G\ \underline{\ \ }\ G\ \underline{\ \ }\quad .$$
An admissible seating pattern can then be constructed as follows:

- Choose an $r$ with $0\leq2r\leq n$.
- Choose $r$ of the $n-1$ inner spaces between the $G$s, and write $B^2$ there. This can be done in ${n-1\choose r}$ ways.
- Choose $n-2r$ of the remaining $n+1-r$ spaces, and write a single $B$ there. This can be done in ${n+1-r\choose n-2r}$ ways.

The total number $P(n)$ of admissible seating patterns therefore comes to
$$P(n)=\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n-1\choose r}\>{n+1-r\choose n-2r}\qquad(n\geq1)\ ,$$
producing the sequence $(2,4,10,26,70,192,\ldots)$, as in Markus Scheuer's answer. Making girls as well as boys distinguishable then gives the number
$$N=(n!)^2 P(n)$$
of personalized seatings.

Comment: Very nice. I was already curious and awaiting your answer similar to your answer of the question I'm referring to :-) (+1)

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** Here we state generating functions for OPs sequence $(g_n)_{n\geq 1}=(2,4,10,26,\ldots)$ and show that the numbers are the sum of consecutive central trinomial coefficients.

\begin{align*}
   g_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}
+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}\qquad\qquad n\geq 1
   \end{align*}

> If we encode boys with $0$ and girls with $1$, we are looking for binary strings of length $2n$ with the following constraints:
>
> - The number of $0$'s is equal to the number of $1$'s, since we have the same number of boys and girls.
> - A substring $000$ is not contained, which corresponds to a configuration BBB and the boy in the middle has not a girl beside him.
> - The string must not start with $00$ and must not end with $00$, since then a boy at the beginning resp. at the end has not a girl beside him.

According to my computations the sequence $(g_n)_{n\geq 1}$ starts with
\begin{align*}
  2,4,10,26,70,192,534,1500,4246,12092
  \end{align*}

The valid configurations for small $n=1,2,3$ are
\begin{align*}
  n=1\qquad&01,10\\
  n=2\qquad&0101,0110,1001,1010\\
  n=3\qquad&010011,010101,010110,011001,011010\\
  &100101,100110,101001,101010,110010
  \end{align*}

> Feeding OEIS with these values gives us the sequence *[A025565](http://oeis.org/A025565)*. Denoting this sequence with $a_n, n\geq 1$, the entries $a_{n+1}$ give the number of UDU free paths of $n$ upsteps (U) and n downsteps (D).
>
> The generating function is
>   \begin{align*}
>   A(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n=x\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-3x}}\\
>   &=x+2x^2+4x^3+10x^4+26x^5+70x^6+192x^7+\cdots
>   \end{align*}

**[2016-02-12]**

> **A regular expression**
>
> We can find a regular expression for all binary strings which *do not contain* three consecutive $0$'s and which do also not contain $00$ at the beginning and at the end of the string. This was already stated by @gar in the *[related example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835008)* as
>
> \begin{align*}
>  ((1+01)1^*0)^*(\varepsilon+(1+01)1^*)\tag{1}
>  \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- $(1+01)$ means we can either start with a girl or a boy followed by a girl
- This may be followed by zero or more occurrences of girls followed by a boy
- This expression may occur zero or more times which gives $((1+01)1^*0)^*$
- The string may end this way $(\varepsilon)$ or end with the sequence $(1+01)1^*$

> Note the binary strings described by (1) do not respect that we need the same number of boys and girls. We will deal with it somewhat later.
>
> Using the notation from *P. Flajolet's* and *R. Sedgewicks* [Analytic Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521898064) we can write the regular expression as
>
> \begin{align*}
>   SEQ((y+xy)SEQ(y)x)(1+(y+xy)SEQ(y))
>   \end{align*}

with the sequence $SEQ(x)$ defined as
\begin{align*}
  SEQ(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-x}
  \end{align*}

> We can now state for (1) the corresponding generating function
>   \begin{align*}
>   S(x,y)&=\frac{1}{(y+xy)\frac{1}{1-y}x}\left(1+(y+xy)\frac{1}{1-y}\right)\\
>     &=\frac{1+xy}{1-y(1+x+x^2)}\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Another generating function**
>
> Since we are looking for strings with the same number of $0$'s and $1$'s we extract the diagonal from $S(x,y)$. We use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. We obtain
>
> A generating function $G(t)=\sum_{n\geq 1}g_nt^n$ for OPs sequence $2,4,10,26,70,192,\ldots$ is
>   \begin{align*}
>   G(t)&=[x^0]S\left(x,\frac{t}{x}\right)\\
> &=[x^0]\frac{1+x\frac{t}{x}}{1-\left(x+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)t}\\
>   &=[x^0]\frac{1+t}{1-\left(x+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)t}\tag{3}\\
>   \end{align*}
>
> **Central trinomial coefficients**
>
> Note the coefficient of $x^0$ in
>    \begin{align*}
>    [x^0](x+1+\frac{1}{x})^k\qquad\qquad k\geq 0
>    \end{align*}
>    are the *[centrial trinomial coefficients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html)*.
>
> We obtain from (3) for $n\geq 1$
>    \begin{align*}
>      [t^n]G(t)&=[t^n][x^0](1+t)\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(x+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^kt^k\\
>      &=[t^n+t^{n-1}][x^0]\sum_{k\geq 0}\left(x+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^kt^k\\
>      &=[x^0]\left(x+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n+[x^0]\left(x+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n-1}
>    \end{align*}

Since for $n\geq 0$
 \begin{align*}
   [x^0]\left(x+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n
   &=[x^0]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^k\\
   &=[x^0]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}x^{2j-k}\\
   &=[x^0]\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{2k}\sum_{j=0}^{2k}\binom{2k}{j}x^{2j-2k}\\
   &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}
   \end{align*}

> We finally obtain the following expression for OPs sequence $(g_n)_{n\geq 1}$
>    \begin{align*}
>    g_n=[t^n]G(t)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}
> +\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}
>    \end{align*}
>
> The central trinomial coefficients $c_n$ can be found in OEIS as *[A002426](http://oeis.org/A002426)*. We get
>    \begin{array}{rlllllll}
>    c_n&1&1&3&7&19&51&141\\
>    g_n=c_n+c_{n-1}&&2&4&10&26&70&192
>    \end{array}

Answer (score 1):

With a perspective of keeping  it simple and $z$ representing boys and
$w$ representing girls we get the generating function

$$(1+z)
\left( \sum_{q\ge 0} \left(\frac{w}{1-w} (z+z^2)\right)^q \right)
\frac{w}{1-w} (1+z).$$

This is
$$(1+z)^2 \frac{w}{1-w} \frac{1}{1-w(z+z^2)/(1-w)}
= w (1+z)^2 \frac{1}{1-w-w(z+z^2)}.$$

Extracting coefficients from this we get

$$[w^n] w (1+z)^2 \frac{1}{1-w-w(z+z^2)}
= (1+z)^2 [w^{n-1}] \frac{1}{1-w(1+z+z^2)}
\\ = (1+z)^2 (1+z+z^2)^{n-1}
= (1+z+z^2)^{n} + z (1+z+z^2)^{n-1}.$$

This yields as the answer the two trinomial coefficients
$$[z^n] (1+z+z^2)^{n} + [z^n] z (1+z+z^2)^{n-1}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z+z^2)^{n} + [z^{n-1}] (1+z+z^2)^{n-1}.$$

Extracting coefficents we get for the first term
$$[z^n] \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} z^q (1+z)^q
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} {q\choose n-q}$$

for a final answer of

$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} {q\choose n-q}
+ \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} {q\choose n-1-q}.$$

Given that we have an excellent answer the above can perhaps provide a
slightly   different  perspective,   thereby  facilitating   a  better
understanding of the computation.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. Maybe you also would like to present the corresponding regular expression $(\varepsilon+0)(1^+0(\varepsilon+0))^*1^+(\varepsilon+0)$ in your answer, which could be nice for comparison. (+1)

Comment: I checked your RE and I will keep it in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Start with two lines, one of boys and one of girls, and imagine constructing the arrangement by picking the first person in one of the lines. You get a factor of 2 every time the choice can be from either line.

This construction is useful because no seating arrangement is double counted, which can be seen by noting that you can retrieve the order the boys (or girls) were in in their monogender lines by skipping the people of another gender.

Comment: Beautiful! So it's $n! \cdot n! \cdot 2^\text{(however many times the choice can be from either line)}$? Is there a nice closed form?

Comment: No form fixed its wrong

Comment: @EliRose: It's not even of that form. See my answer.

Comment: @user21820: Interesting. I can see that some of the numbers in your table are odd, so it must not be, but why isn't it? Does it have to do with the fact that whether the current choice can be from either line depends on the last choice?

Comment: @EliRose: Absolutely right. You can't multiply when the number of ways of performing each subtask is not independent of the history of choices.