# In how many ways can 18 girls and 15 boys sit in a row such that just the girls are always next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can 18 girls and 15 boys sit in a row such that just the girls are always next to each other?

Now I have 2 * 18! x 15!

But I am not sure with this.

Comment: It seems you may want all the girls in a row together with some boys on each side of the girls. Your answer is too big thanks to your $33!$

Comment: $33!$ is the number of ways of arranging all 33 of the people where we have no additional restrictions.  Only some but not all of those ways will be "good" ways so we know the answer will be less than $33!$.  Your answer is much much larger than $33!$.

Comment: The meaning is unclear. If girls never sit next to boys, then the boys could not all be seated without leaving a gap between the girls and the boys.  On the other hand perhaps it is meant that each girl sits next to at least one other girl.

Comment: Yes, we got unclear assignment at school. But it should be that each girl sits next to at least one other girl.

Comment: If the assignment is unclear, only your teacher can help you.  There are many questions this can be, each of which can be answered, but there is no way to know if we are answering the right one.  I could imagine that each girl must have a girl neighbor, that all 18 girls are together with boys on one or both ends of the row, that no boys have a boy for a neighbor.  There are very different questions.

Answer (score 2):

If just the girls can sit togeher , then all of the boys must be separate from one another. Then arrange the girls by $18!$ ways in the row  , this arrangement gives $19$ possible places for boys including end points and gaps between girls .You can place the boys by $P(19,15)$ or $C(19,15)15!$. Then , $$18! \times P(19,15)$$

Comment: This is an interpretation that I had not thought of, but it echoes [an earlier Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834985/in-how-many-ways-can-4-girls-and-3-boys-sit-in-a-row-such-that-just-the-girls-ar) for which one of the Answers describes the counts for two slightly differently posed problems.

Answer (score 0):

Out of 33 places, there are only 33-18+1= 16 places to place the row of 18 girls, by wich there are 18! possible ways of sitting the girls once the row is placed, by which there are 15! way of sitting the boys, so the answer is
$$16×18!×15!$$

Comment: Or $16!×18!$, by treating the girl block like each individual boy.